# Arguments in tomcat 7 in intellij idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using the latest intellij idea and tomcat 7.
In the VM argument I have this line:

```
-Dmysql_datasource_jdbc_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8&amp;useUnicode=true
-Dmysql_datasource_username=test
-Dmysql_datasource_password=test
```

When trying to start tomcat i get this output.

```
Disconnected from server
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: amp: not found 
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval:-Dmysql_datasource_username=test: not found`
```

The same configuration runs fine in eclipse

EDIT
Thanks to @GreyBeardedGeek i have replaced the "&amp ;" with "&" and this part works.

But i still get an error when trying to set the username and pass for the db login. Both work on eclipse fine.

EDIT2
Seems that whatever arguments follows

-Dmysql_datasource_jdbc_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true

throws the same error so i guess there is something with this argument wrong. Any help please i have searched everywhere?
By the way i have tried using only the above argument and it still fails

Comment: try replacing "&amp;" in the url with "&"

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes... Worked for me.

```
-Dmysql_datasource_jdbc_url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true'
```